# Ruby on Rails: Yield content_for Display Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-for

Using 2.3.8 of rails.

In the view template I have this type of code

```
<%content_for :sidebar do %>
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p><%=link_to "somewhere", "http://www.google.com/"%></p>
<% end %>

<h1>Pictures#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pictures/new.html.erb</p>
```

In the application.html.erb template I have

```
<!-- END: Header -->
<%= yield(:sidebar) %>
</div>

<div class="gb">
<%= yield %>
```

When I go to view the page in a browser instead of showing the code correctly in named yield it is escaping all the tags. EG;

```
&lt;h2&gt;Sidebar&lt;/h2&gt;
  &lt;p&gt;<a href="http://www.google.com/">somewhere</a>&lt;/p&gt;
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong. Help! Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you aren't using <%=h yield(:sidebar) %> ?

Answer (score 0):

I see a random `</div>` in your application.html.erb file--maybe that's causing the problem?

Comment: I don't understand?

Could you provide more detail.

Comment: There's an end div tag, but it doesn't seem to be preceded by a beginning div tag

Comment: I've boiled the application.html.erb file to just these two lines

<%= yield :sidebar %>
<%= yield %>

and it is still doing the escaping of tags